# Jquery Animation Occurs Twice on Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these divs called tags that are small then when you click on them they expand and the hidden elements inside are displayed. an X (**< p >< span > X < / span > < / p >** ) also shows up. This tag(div) should close when this X is clicked.

In Firefox, the tag opens fine. Then on close it closes and reopens. I can't figure out why the close is followed by an open.

By the way, I cannot get the first 3 lines to work at all.

**Keep in mind, it works fine on Chrome. So Firefox is interpreting the Jquery differently**

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row row1">
      <div id="tag1" class="tag">
        <p class="p1">Header</p>
        <video id="VideoA1" class="VideoA" name="media">
          <source src="">
          <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="" type="video/mv4">
        </video>
        <p id="X"><span id="X" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-label="Close"></span></p>
        <iframe id="player1" class="ytplayer" width="390" height="220" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <p class="text">Random Text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//This will make the tags expand to take up the whole row when clicked
   $(".row .tag").on('click', function(event1){

 if(event1.target.id == "tag1") {
   alert("hello");
   return; //Do nothing if the X is closed
 }
else {

$(this).siblings().hide();
$(this).animate({
  width:"98%",
});
$(".VideoA", this).css('display', 'none');
$("img", this).addClass('offleft');
$(".tag").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("cursor","default")
});
$(".glyphicon-remove", this).delay(1000).show();
$(".glyphicon-remove", this).parent().show();
$('iframe',this).show();
$('.text',this).show();
}
});


$(".row1 .glyphicon-remove").click(function(){

 var clicked = this;
 $(this).parent().hide();
 $(".row1 iframe").hide();
 $(".row1 .text").hide();
 $(this).parent().parent().animate({
   width: "400px",
 },function(){
  $(".row1 .VideoA").show();
  $("img", this).removeClass('offleft');
  $(".tag",this).css('cursor','pointer');
  $(clicked).parent().parent().siblings().show();
});
event.stopPropagation();
});


$(".row2 .glyphicon-remove").click(function(){
var clicked = this;
$(this).parent().hide();
$(".row2 iframe").hide();
$(".row2 .text").hide();
$(this).parent().parent().animate({
  width: "400px",
},function(){
  $(".row2 .VideoA").show();
  $("img", this).removeClass('offleft');
  $(".tag",this).css('cursor','pointer');
  $(clicked).parent().parent().siblings().show();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Missing closing `"` at `<source src=">`

Comment: That is just a typo from when I sanitized my HTML. Not the cause of any issues.

Comment: `event` is undefined. Inject `event` as`$(".row2 .glyphicon-remove").click(function(event){`. otherwise `stopPropagation` is useless

Comment: The first three lines?

Comment: I need to inject `event` just for the 3rd snippet (the .row2 one)? Is this because that is the only one with `stop propagation`?

Comment: @mani that worked when I added `event` to both snippets of JS that called on the `.glyphicon-remove` class (for `.row1` and `.row2`)

Please submit this as an answer with an explanation and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is undefined.

Inject `event` as `$(".row2 .glyphicon-remove").click(function(event){`. otherwise `stopPropagation` is useless.

I think, Chrome is strict, and on `undefined` it stops evaluation of the current function i.e. it throws an error when it encounters an `undefined` value and stops evaluation JS for that particular closure.

However, seems firefox continues evaluation and bubbles the `click` up the DOM tree. So, in your case, the `event` of clicking needs to be consumed by your function, and therefore it is required to manually `stopPropagation` by calling `event.stopPropagation()` and injecting `event` into your closure, or you could simply also `return false` at the end of your function as it is a jquery [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which is the same as calling  `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

e.g.

```
    $(".row2 .glyphicon-remove").click(function(event){
    //stop propagation for the event but continue to evaluate current function
    event.stopPropagation(); 
      var clicked = this;
      $(this).parent().hide();
      $(".row2 iframe").hide();
      $(".row2 .text").hide();
      $(this).parent().parent().animate({
        width: "400px",
      },function(){
        $(".row2 .VideoA").show();
        $("img", this).removeClass('offleft');
        $(".tag",this).css('cursor','pointer');
        $(clicked).parent().parent().siblings().show();
      });
    return false; //jquery event stop propagation + prevent default    
    });
```